# KiCad placement using coordinate system

Tags: pcb, layout, kicad

I am new to KiCad but have extensive experience with Allegro:

The goal create a rectangular board outline that is 55 x 30 mm with the top left corner at x,y 0,0.

This is possible in OrCad through the command line prompt. Is there a similar way to type in the dimension in KiCad versus moving around the cursor till you get to the right spots?

Answer (score 1):

There's not, as far as I know, a command line way to do this. You can do it be editing the `.kicad_pcb` file directly. Steps are:

1. In Pcbnew, draw out an outline anywhere. You'll want to use the `Add graphic line` tool (shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-L`) and use the `Edge.Cuts` layer. Save this file, and close Pcbnew.
2. Open the saved file in your text editor, and search for `Edge`. There will be entries for the outline you've drawn, starting `(gr_line [..]`. You can then edit this to give your desired coordinates. Save the file, and re-open in Pcbnew, and you're good to go.

For your board, it would be:

```
(gr_line (start 0 0) (end 0 30) (layer Edge.Cuts) (width 0.05))
(gr_line (start 0 30) (end 55 30) (layer Edge.Cuts) (width 0.05))
(gr_line (start 55 30) (end 55 0) (layer Edge.Cuts) (width 0.05))
(gr_line (start 55 0) (end 0 0) (layer Edge.Cuts) (width 0.05))
```

Alternatively, go to `(0,0)`, and just set your grid to `1 mm` then you can draw it directly.

Comment: Thanks this is the approach I took, but also placing my components at the board origin which is 0, 0 then using the move exact to be able to type in exact x, y dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

at the bottom of kicad you can see X,Y axis so you can calculate the persice dimensions you want. You can use your arrow keys for precision also you can use the line tool draw for example 55mm line copy paste it on more time and do the same thing for 30mm then place the at the start of the X,Y axis.Another efficient way is to import the outline of the board from another CAD rogram in kicad documentation there are instructions on the specific files that supports.